# What is the probability that one person does not sit next to another.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

5 people around a round table. (A,B,C,D,E)

They are placed randomly with equal probabilities of being placed in a seat.

What is the probability that A does not sit next to C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you seat A first, how many seats aren't next to A?

Comment: 2. oh so it's 1/2. I didn't realize how easy it was #hiding thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are $5!=120$ options for placing $5$ people.

In each of the following options, $A$ sits next to $C$:

1. $AC---$
2. $CA---$
3. $-AC--$
4. $-CA--$
5. $--AC-$
6. $--CA-$
7. $---AC$
8. $---CA$
9. $C---A$
10. $A---C$

In each one of these options, there are $3!=6$ ways for placing the remaining $3$ people.

Therefore, $A$ sits next to $C$ in $60$ out of $120$ options.

Therefore, $A$ doesn't sit next to $C$ in $60$ out of $120$ options.

Therefore, the probability that $A$ doesn't sit next to $C$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.